# pycparser ParseError on barrier.h

Tags: linux-kernel, pycparser

I am trying to creat AST for a kernel file using pyCparser and met ParseError.

1. I preprocessed the file using command like, and no error generated.

   `clang -E -D'__attribute__(x)=' -D'__extension__=' -D'__signed__=signed' -D'__builtin_va_list=int' ...-c -o /mnt/os_tmp/cparser/test1/clk-pp.c linux/drivers/clk/xx/clk.c`
2. I met errors when parse the file with commands:

   ```
   pycparser.parse_file('/mnt/os_tmp/cparser/test1/clk-pp.c')

   pycparser.plyparser.ParseError: linux/arch/arm64/include/asm/barrier.h:77:6: before: volatile
   ```

barrier.h:72

```
     static inline unsigned long array_index_mask_nospec(unsigned long idx,
                             unsigned long sz)
 {
     unsigned long mask;
 
     asm volatile(
     "   cmp %1, %2\n"
     "   sbc %0, xzr, xzr\n"
     : "=r" (mask)
     : "r" (idx), "Ir" (sz)
     : "cc");
 
     csdb();
     return mask;
 }
```

Can somebody help me on the issue？

Comment: This is not a complete answer, so leaving a comment. Please read and re-read https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/on-parsing-c-type-declarations-and-fake-headers/ -- it explains all you need to know here

Comment: `asm volatile` is a gcc-extension for C, so pycparser cannot parse it. You may try to eliminate `asm` and `volatile` via preprocessor (by additional `-D` flags).